# gradle buildscript "name" variable resolution not working

Tags: gradle, groovy, closures, build.gradle

Below are th contents of my `build.gradle`

```
class Human {
    Integer age;
    String name;
    String surName;

    Human(name, age, surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.surName = surname;
    }

    def executeInside(Closure c) {
        c.delegate = this
        c()
    }
}

def h1 = new Human("John", 43, "Smith");
def hc = {
    println "My name is ${name} and my age is ${age} and my surname is ${surName}"
}

h1.executeInside(hc)

hc.delegate = h1
hc()
```

When executing the script I should be getting `My name is John and my age is 43 and my surname is Smith`
 But instead I am getting 
`My name is mygradlefoldername and my age is 43 and my surname is Smith`

If I run this above script in `groovyConsole` , it works correctly, but what is going on in this gradle build script such that name is not correctly printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name is already reserved and it correctly points to project directory:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html
[image]

Change the property name in Human class to something like firstName and it will work

Comment: Thanks, I relaized the reason for this, probably the owner of the closure is the script/project which is consulted first in delegate resolution chain. I was able to override it using `hc.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`